# launch bbm programmatically

Tags: blackberry, messenger

How can we launch a blackberry messenger programmatically. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  As far as I know the following would get the BlackberryMessenger instance but what can be done to launch the BBM:

```
BlackBerryMessenger bbm= BlackBerryMessenger.getInstance();
```

Comment: What OS are you programming against? Up to OS 7.1 BBM is always running if installed.

Comment: I'm currently testing in my simulator whose OS version is 7.1 but my device has 5.0 version OS. What I want my app to do is to launch the BBM. So I need a way to programmatically launch BBM so that the BBM app comes in foreground.

Comment: I don't see that as a productive line of thought. Switching context from your app to BBM will be confusing to users and goes against the recommended platform behaviour. The user can switch to BBM at any time using the "Switch Application" menu. Do you have a reason not to use the BBM API to have your app act directly through the BBM protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still urge you to consider my comments above, but you should be able to cause BBM to come to the foreground with:

```
int modHandle = CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandle( <bbm module name> );
ApplicationDescriptor[] apDes = CodeModuleManager.getApplicationDescriptors( modHandle ); 
ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().runApplication(apDes [ 0 ] );
```

You will have to find out what the appropriate module name is and put that string in the call to getModuleHandle(). BBM has a bunch of modules and I don't know off hand which one is the main one.

Comment: Hi,i'm using the same code it's opening in simulator,but not working in device 9300